# Connect and Print in th esc/pos mobile printerusing ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am thinking to develop a Android application related  to connect a Bluetooth POS printer and print the same in printer ...once connected device in local starage and transaction details are stored in local db and sync to server on daily basis .. I I have limited experience in dotnet as well as angular. Is xamarin or ionic is best suited for my  requirement please suggest

**EDIT: i need  sample solution ionic latest version application
which  print  in the esc/pos thermal printer  take the  printer from  Paired  devices  (Printer is able to auto connect to mobile)**

Please any experienced in suggest me a print the simple text in  pos portable printer ( For ex: https://www.tvs-e.in/mp-280-lite/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried Xamarin, but I have been developing Ionic from a simple mobile application until a quite complex POS application by using Ionic and the result is pretty decent.

Regarding the printing functionality, I have updated the demo application in Ionic 5. Check it out. :)

[ESC Pos Encoder Demo (Ionic 5)](https://github.com/Ans0n-Ti0/esc-pos-encoder-ionic-demo)

Comment: The demo should work, but I haven't got the chance to test the demo by using a Bluetooth thermal printer (because holiday). Tomorrow I will test it.

Comment: Thanks .. minimum 1 day accept and award ..I will accept and award tomorrow

Comment: Am new to ionic...Is  esc-pos-encoder-ionic  extension is mandatory? I need to less dependents on external extension..thanks

Comment: esc-pos-encoder-ionic is not mandatory, the library is a list of helper functions which translates the into the byte stream. You can also refer to the list of available command in https://github.com/Ans0n-Ti0/EscPosEncoder/blob/master/src/esc-pos-encoder.js

Comment: One last query...is solution automatically detects the paied device? Or how can I save paired device in local storage

Comment: My current demo does not automatically pair the device. So the user needs to pair the Bluetooth device and manually type in the Bluetooth MAC address. 
To edit the MAC address, please refer to https://github.com/Ans0n-Ti0/esc-pos-encoder-ionic-demo/blob/main/EscPosDemo/src/app/tab2/tab2.page.ts

Comment: When I have spare time, I would update my demo application to support Bluetooth device selection. Hopefully, I can update before Tuesday next week.

Comment: @Cheezy I have run in my mobile...link in Tab 1 are not redirect.. Can u pls check

Comment: @Glen I tested on my application, it works ok, if you do not mind let's continue on github issue https://github.com/Ans0n-Ti0/esc-pos-encoder-ionic-demo/issues/7

Comment: blue tooth prints only one time...after am getting connection issues..if I close reopens then some time it prints..do you know what could be the reason..pls help I tried lot ..but no lock... waiting for ur reply

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Ionic if you don't have experience within .Net.
Ionic is only using Web technology and Angular or React or Vue Framework.

You have some exemple to use direct connection to Bluetooth Printers :

- [How to connect bluetooth printer using ionic 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46947164/how-to-connect-bluetooth-printer-using-ionic-3)
- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-print-on-a-bluetooth-printer-using-your-ionic-application-ceabc45abf75

There is a lot of sample on Github.

Comment: Thanks..I have knowledge in dot.net  but don't no about xamarin. ionic framework refrsh token is necessary? because I small but sensitive information app needs to send to api..

Comment: If you talk about OAuth2 / JWT Token, it's another topic that could be discussed separatly. Quick answer: if your API is secured by OAuth2/JWT Token : yes, you've to provide an access token. A refresh token is needed only if your access token is expired.